# I am trying to add at the back of the linked list but i keep getting segmentation error, can someone explain why?

Tags: c++

```
//creaing a linked list
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

 struct node {
   int data;
  node *next;
   };

  node *head = NULL;
  node *tail = NULL;
```

This is to add to the front of the linked list

```
void addToFront(int insert){      

node *temp = new node();
temp->data = insert;
temp->next = head;
head = temp;
    }
```

This will transverse the linked list

```
void Transverse(){
node *temp1 = new node();
temp1 = head;
while(temp1!=NULL){
cout << temp1->data << endl;
temp1 = temp1 ->next;
tail = temp1;
}
}
```

This is the part of the code I am having problems with by add to the back function

```
void addToBack(int insert){
node * temp = new node();
temp -> data = insert;
temp -> next = NULL;
if(head==NULL){
    head=temp;
}
else{

    node * temp2= new node();
    while(temp2!=NULL){
        temp2 = temp2 -> next;
    }
    temp2->next= temp;


    }

   }

      int main(){


addToBack(4);
addToFront(1);
addToFront(2);
addToFront(3);
addToBack(4);
Transverse();
return 0;
      }
```

Comment: Think for a little while about where `temp2` is pointing (in particular, `temp2->next`) and how it's related to your list. (Pencil and paper are extremely useful for debugging linked lists.)

Comment: What happens when you call `addToFront` to add the very first node in the list? Where will the `tail` point to? Actually, what do you use the `tail` variable for?

Comment: I dont think i have used the tail variable at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the else branch you might want this:

`node * temp2 = head;
    while(temp2->next != NULL){
        temp2 = temp2 -> next;
    }
    temp2->next= temp;`

Comment: This fixed the problem but can you explain what I just changed and why?

Comment: The code just walks on the linked list from head until it reaches the last node. If you would use the tail pointer this would not be necessary, but you don't. At the end it just adds the new node.

Comment: Ahhh! node * temp2= new node(); this part of my code temp 2 wasn't really pointing at anything so why it wouldn't loop through right?

Comment: Thanks for your answer :D